# Not subspace, but closed under addition and under taking additive inverses?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

My linear algebra book ([Linear Algebra Done Right](http://www.cin.ufpe.br/~jrsl/Books/Linear%20Algebra%20Done%20Right%20-%20Sheldon%20Axler.pdf) by Sheldon Axler) has the following problem as exercise 1.6:

> Give an example of a nonempty subset $U$ of $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $U$ is closed under addition and under taking additive inverses (meaning $-u \in U$ whenever $u \in U$), but $U$ is not a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

It seems to me that such a set cannot exist, since the only subspace condition it's not mandated to fulfill is containing $0$, and for any $u \in U$, I can negate it to get $-u$ and then get $u + (-u) = 0$.

What is going on?

Comment: $0$ is not the issue here. Try $\mathbb{Q}^2$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: Consider all ordered pairs $(a,b)$ where $a$ and $b$ are **integers**.  Or, a little simpler, all ordered pairs $(a,0)$ where $a$ ranges over the integers.

Comment: Ah, I forgot that $U$ needs to be a vector space in its own right. Thanks.

Comment: You are welcome. Closure under scalar multiplication fails.